# How many rows selected?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+-----------------+
| id |    timestamp    |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | 1452001861      |    -- yesterday
| 2  | 1452088272      |    -- today
| 3  | 1452088283      |    -- today
| 4  | 1451915461      |    -- last week
| 5  | 1452001861      |    -- yesterday
| 6  | 1452088263      |    -- today
| 7  | 1252388263      |    -- out of {today, yesterday, last week}
| 8  | 1452088312      |    -- today
| 9  | 1452001762      |    -- yesterday
| 10 | 1222388263      |    -- out of {today, yesterday, last week}
| 12 | 1451915459      |    -- last week
+----+-----------------+
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
   WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
   ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

The above query select all rows with are between now and 7 last days.

---

Now sometimes all rows are before 7 last days *(I mean is the newest row is for example added in 8 last days)* and then the output of that query will be nothing (0 row selected).

What I want is, if there is no row selected (0 rows), then select 5 last rows *(which were added earlier)*. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
SET @row_count := (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM mytable 
                   WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);

IF (@row_count > 0) THEN
    SELECT * 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
ELSE
    SELECT * 
    FROM mytable 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 5;
END IF;
```

Comment: Seems correct, But it is optimize? I think it needs to a lot of processing ..! Hum?

Comment: AS the first query is only there to get a count you could remove the `ORDER BY` to reduce the load a little

Comment: I also think I read somewhere that `count(id)` for example is quicker that `count(*)` probably even better if its an indexed field

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah you have a valid point ORDER was not needed for count

Comment: @RiggsFolly BTW, I believe we can remove both first and second `order by`, We just need to the third `order by`. Am I right?

Comment: This `*` or `id` thing is more complicated than I thought https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: @stack I would probably say No to removing both `ORDER BY` but its your data and your result, so you should know best what you need. Remember its only going to run ONE of the queries in the `IF ELSE`

Comment: Oh one thing else, can I store `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY` in a variable and use it twice?

Comment: I gota say this - Why? and for what benefit

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok I was wrong ..! I thought it makes that query faster.. Never mind

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sure ..! But why? do you think this query is perfect and there isn't any better solution?

Comment: Well you can always change your mind if you see a better answer